# Split data in r and save all the split files in csv

Tags: r, csv, split

I have a dataset named data

```
  Model Garage        City    
  Honda      C     Chicago       
 Maruti      B      Boston  
Porsche      A    New York    
  Honda      B     Chicago  
  Honda      C    New York
```

It is 100000 rows and I want to split this data by car,location and city and also save the split files in different csv's.

```
split(Data, with(Data, interaction(Model,City,Garage)), drop = TRUE)
```

Now this code makes it a list. How do I unlist and save different csv files for all split types

Ex- Honda will have three split files as `Honda C Chicago`, `Honda B Chicago` and `Honda C New York`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create all combinations of data.frames possible based on unique values of Model, Garage, City
l = split(x, list(x$Model, x$Garage, x$City))

# create csv filrs only if data.frame had any rows in it
lapply(names(l), function(x) if(dim(l[[x]])[1] != 0){write.csv(l[[x]], paste0("path", x,".csv"))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more options, you can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
x <- as.data.table(x)
x[, write.table(.SD, paste("path/file_", Model, "_", Garage, "_", City, ".csv", sep = "")), by = c("Model", "Garage", "City")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could easily use a loop. that shouldn't be a problem with 100k or so lines.

```
x <- read.table(text = "Model, Garage, City
                   Honda, C, Chicago
                   Maruti, B, Boston
                   Porsche, A, New York
                   Honda, B, Chicago
                   Honda, C, New York", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
x   
#   Model Garage      City
#   Honda      C   Chicago
#  Maruti      B    Boston
# Porsche      A  New York
#   Honda      B   Chicago
#   Honda      C  New York

library(dplyr)
```

you just iterate over all unique combinations of Model, Garage and City, `filter` them from your `data.frame` and export the temporary `data.frame` to a csv table.

```
uni <- unique(x[,c("Model", "Garage", "City")])

for (j in 1:nrow(uni)) {
  i <- uni[j,]
  tmp <- x %>% filter(Model == i$Model, Garage == i$Garage, City == i$City)

  write.table(tmp, paste(i$Model, "_", i$City, "_", i$Garage, ".csv"))
}
```